# SQL Server : comparing variables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm pretty new with stored procedures, and I have to make a comparison with two dates, to know if they are equal or not.

If the dates are equal, I have to return just one of these, else, I have to return the two dates.

With this code, the return is coming into an integer number, that I can't indentify.

this is the code:

```
CASE
  WHEN gru.date1 = gru.date2 THEN 
    CONVERT (CHAR(11), gru.date2,103)
  ELSE
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), gru.date1,103) + CHAR(32)+CHAR(97)+CHAR(32) + CONVERT(CHAR(11), gru.date2,103)
END date'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why this isn't returnig a date type. hehehehe

Comment: Is one of your dates NULL?

Comment: This dates never return null.

Comment: What is it returning then?  Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the dates are being interpereted as numbers and being added.  you need to concatenate a blank onto the beginning of your concatenation, in order for them to be proerly identified as strings:

```
CASE
  WHEN gru.date1 = gru.date2 THEN 
    CONVERT (CHAR(11), gru.date2,103)
  ELSE
    ''+ CONVERT(CHAR(10), gru.date1,103) + CHAR(32)+CHAR(97)+CHAR(32) + CONVERT(CHAR(11), gru.date2,103)
END date
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e8bd/7

Comment: your sqlfiddle works without the blank at the beginning